# How is $\frac{1}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}'|} = \frac{1}{r} - \vec{r} \cdot \triangledown \frac{1}{r} + \ldots$ a Taylor expansion?

Tags: taylor-expansion

From pg. 112 of *No-Nonsense Electrodynamics*, the author uses multivariable Taylor expansion to assert:

> [image]

In case it matters, the author is also assuming that $|\vec{r}| \gg | \vec{r}'|$ (stated elsewhere in the text).  Also, $\vec{r}, \vec{r}'$ are both 3-dimensional vectors.

**Question:** How does this identity follow from Taylor?  According to Wikipedia

> A second-order Taylor series expansion of a scalar-valued function of more than one variable can be written compactly as
>
> $$T(\mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{a}) + (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{a})^\mathsf{T} D f(\mathbf{a})  + \cdots$$

where $D$ in this context denotes the gradient $\triangledown$ operator.  If we plug this into to our context we get

$$
f(\mathbf{a}) + (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{a})^T Df(\mathbf{a}) = \frac{1}{r} + ( \vec{r} - \vec{r}') \cdot \triangledown \frac{1}{| \vec{r} - \vec{r}' |}
$$

which doesn't obviously resemble the formula the author derived, unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

We can write the term of interest as

$$\begin{align}
\frac1{|\vec r-\vec r'|}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|\vec r|^2+|\vec r'|^2-2\vec r'\cdot\vec r}}\\\\
&=\frac1{|\vec r|}\left(1-2\frac{\vec r'\cdot\vec r}{|\vec r|^2}+\left(\frac{|\vec r'|}{|\vec r|}\right)^2\right)^{-1/2}
\end{align}$$

---

Now applying the binomial theorem (which is a special case of Taylor's Theorem) reveals

$$\begin{align}
\frac1{|\vec r-\vec r'|}&=\frac1{|\vec r|}\left(1+\frac{\vec r'\cdot\vec r}{|\vec r|^2}+O\left(\frac{|\vec r'|^2}{|\vec r|^2}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\frac1{|\vec r|}+\vec r'\cdot \frac{\vec r}{|\vec r|^3}+O\left(\frac{|\vec r'|^2}{|\vec r|^3}\right)
\end{align}$$

and we see that the Equation $(4.30)$ in the OP is incorrect by a factor of $-1$ on the second term of the expansion.  In fact, $(4.30)$ is inconsistent with the equation that precedes it since $\nabla \frac1r=-\frac{\vec r}{|\vec r|^3}$ and not $\nabla \frac1r=+\frac{\vec r}{|\vec r|^3}$

---

**NOTE:**

Application of Taylor's Theorem to the function $\frac1{|\vec r-\vec r'|}$ that led to the expression written in the OP is $o(|\vec r-\vec r'|)$ and does not lead, therefore, to a useful expansion when $|\vec r|>>|\vec r'|$.

Instead, we have used Taylor's Theorem (which is also application of the binomial theorem in this case) to expand the term $\displaystyle \left(1-2\frac{\vec r'\cdot\vec r}{|\vec r|^2}+\left(\frac{|\vec r'|}{|\vec r|}\right)^2\right)^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Hi Mark -- I'm just coming across this answer and all makes sense to me. However, I'm still not entirely clear on why the straightforward way of computing the Taylor expansion $ \frac{1}{| \bf{r}-\bf{r'}|}=\frac{1}{r} + \bf{r'}$$ \cdot \triangledown \frac{1}{r}+...$ is incorrect (where, in particular, I call out the plus sign which exists in my expansion versus the minus sign in the correct one). I'd appreciate any light you could shine on this!

Comment: Hi @EE18.   I'm unsure as to your definition of "the straightforward way of computing the Taylor expansion."

Comment: Sorry, I should've been clearer. I suppose what I mean is that I would have gone right from the definition, where $f(\bf{r}$-$\bf{r'}$$) = f(\bf{r}$$) + \bf{r'}$$ \cdot \nabla f(\bf{r}$$)+...$. That is to say, right from the definition in terms of derivatives, rather than with the original manipulation you do to extract $1/r$.

Comment: @EE18 Let $x=1/r$.  Now expand the function $f(x)=\left(1-2(\vec r'\cdot \hat r)x+r'^2 x^2\right)^{-1/2}$ around $x=0$.  Then, multiply this by $x$ and reset $x$ to $\frac1r$.  What do you obtain?

Comment: I agree that it gives your result, and that's what I just noted in my EM textbook. I guess I'm wondering why the expansion I gave is wrong? Do I somehow err in expanding somewhere where it's singular?

Comment: The variable to expand is $x=1/r$ and not $r$.  So, $(r^2-2(\vec r'\cdot \hat r)r+r'^2)^{-1/2}=(1/x^2-2(\vec r'\cdot \hat r)(1/x)+r'^2)^{-1/2}$.  Does that help?